# How to make Mendeley and Zotero detect the folder structure created in windows

Tags: mendeley, zotero

I have created a main folder and a number of subfolders each containing scientific articles.

Is there a way that I can add the main folder in [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) or [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/) and they automatically detect the folder structure and add the articles to the corresponding subfolder?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Folder Import plugin https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-folder-import: import a folder of attachment files into a Zotero collection hierarchy. Useful for transitioning to Zotero from a manual folder-based organization system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).